# Multiple Flat Buttons linked to different listView then how to grey out (unfocus) the ones that is not selected

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui, material-design

I'm trying to build app where 3 flat buttons will be there in a row, first button will be selected by default and will show a listView widget. The other two needs to be greyed out until selected which then will show other listView widget.
Only one button needs to be focused at a time other needs to be greyed out.
Searched out many articles but couldn't find any satisfactory solution.

Comment: It looks like you'll want to use a TabBar: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs. It allows you to define a button (a tab) and assign a Widget to display for each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a state variable. I have written a working example for you.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => FooState();
}

class FooState extends State<Foo> {
  int buttonSelected = 0;
  List<String> list1 = ["1st list"];
  List<String> list2 = ["2nd list"];
  List<String> list3 = ["3rd list"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            getButton(0),
            getButton(1),
            getButton(2),
          ],
        ),
        getBody(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget getButton(int index) {
    return FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            buttonSelected = index;
          });
        },
        color: buttonSelected == index ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
        child: Text("button $index"));
  }

  Widget getBody() {
    if (buttonSelected == 0) {
      return getListView(list1);
    } else if (buttonSelected == 1) {
      return getListView(list2);
    } else {
      return getListView(list3);
    }
  }

  Widget getListView(List<String> currentList) {
    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: currentList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
          return new Text(currentList[index]);
        });
  }
}
```

You can then show content based on buttonSelected value.

If you would like to have a better seperation betweem logic and presentation layer I can highly recommend checking out [Bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc). Multiple examples given there.

Comment: Thanks, your answer has solved my problem. One small question: How to show the list on the click of these buttons assuming there are three buttons and three lists.

Comment: I edit my post, such that it contains a body with a listview as asked in the question.